# C "string" init - which is better?

Tags: c, string

What is the difference between these two initializations?

```
char a[] = "string literal";

char *p  = "string literal";
```

Comment: Duplicate: stackoverflow.com/questions/7886972/difference-between-char-and-char

Comment: If this was asked so many times, why people answer instead of closing?

Comment: @sidyll: because people answer questions to gain rep rather than check for duplicates

Comment: Read the [comp.lang.c faq](http://c-faq.com). Section 6 is about arrays and pointers and why they aren't the same --- start with that section.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between char s\[\] and char *s in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704407/what-is-the-difference-between-char-s-and-char-s-in-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each forces the compiler to create a string literal in static memory that's (at least conceptually) read-only.

The first then uses that to initialize the contents of an array. The string literal is just used to pick its size, and to initialize it.

The second creates a pointer directly to the original string literal itself.

There is no real better or worse between them. They're just different. For example, the array usually uses more memory (there's a string literal, then there's a complete copy of the string  literal in your array). Since it's an otherwise normal array, however, you can modify it if necessary.

The pointer directly to the string literal will often save some memory. It also means you can assign a different value to the pointer so that it (for example) points at different string literals at different times. You are *not*, however, allowed to modify the data it points at -- doing so will give undefined behavior.

Answer (score 17):

Although the two look similar and are often used interchangeably, they do mean different things. The first line:

```
char a[] = "string literal";
```

... creates an array that is large enough to hold the string literal, including its NUL terminator. It initializes this array with the string literal you specified. One benefit of this version is that the array can be modified at a later time. Also, the array's size is known even at compile time, so you can use the `sizeof` operator to determine its size. For example:

```
printf("%u\n",unsigned(sizeof(a))); // Will display 15, which is the array's size 
                                    // including the NUL terminator
```

The second line:

```
char *p  = "string literal";
```

... just sets a pointer to point to a string literal. This is faster than the first version, but you have the drawback that the literal should not be changed, because it may reside in a page marked as read only. You also have the drawback that to know the length of the string, you will need to use the `strlen()` function, since the `sizeof` operator will just give you the size of the pointer variable. For example:

```
printf("%u\n",unsigned(sizeof(p))); // Will likely display 4 or 8, depending on
                                    // whether this is a 32-bit or 64-bit build
printf("%u\n",unsigned(strlen(p))); // Will display the correct length of 14, not
                                    // including the NUL terminator
```

As to which is better, it depends on what you will be doing with these variables. If you do not need to make any changes to the string, use the later, but **do** change the `char *` to a `const char *`, so that you don't accidently attempt making changes to the characters being pointed to. If you do intend to change the data, use the former array based version which allows you to make changes to the array after initialization.

Comment: It's actually wiser to use a `char const *` in the second example, but compilers are obliged to accept the `char *` version due to a backward-compatible wart in the standard.

Comment: @larsmans, I've added this fact to my answer in order to make it more complete. Thanks...

Comment: I see you've added some C++ output examples to the answer, but the OP did label it C...

Comment: `unsigned(sizeof(p))` in not valid C in 2011 and 2019.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you need.

```
char a[] = "string literal";
```

Creates a *mutable* character array with automatic storage duration.  This is legal:

```
a[0] = 'c';
```

On the other hand...

```
char *p  = "string literal";
```

Creates a pointer to readonly memory.  The declaration should really be

```
const char *p  = "string literal";
```

You cannot legally modify what `p` points to.

Answer (score 0):

The first declares an array and fill it (by setting the elements one by one, till the ending null byte included). The array can be modified.

The second declares a pointer, and fill it by setting it to a constant literal. You can modify the pointer (e.g. to make it point elsewhere), but you cannot modify the constant string (which on most systems will be put in a read only segment) pointed by it.

Answer (score 0):

One gives you an array filled with the data you specify, the second gives you a pointer to some memory (typically read-only) somewhere, containing the data you specified.

To make the difference in "what you get" more clear, try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
  char a[] = "string literal";
  char *b = "string literal";

  printf("a is %lu bytes, b is %lu\n", (unsigned long) sizeof a,
                                       (unsigned long) sizeof b);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Here is a [live demo](http://www.ideone.com/ECeVo) with the above code.